# Use play WS 2.5.x from Akka actor

Tags: playframework, java-8, akka, httpclient, playframework-2.5

I'm using akka with java and looking for a way to use asynchronous Play WS api from within akka actors.

In play WS 2.4.x the method `WSRequest.get()` returns an `F.Promise` which easily can be converted to Scala `Future` and then piped with `akka.pattern.Patterns.pipe` to some akka actor in order the http response to be received as an akka message.

In play WS 2.5.x the method `WSRequest.get()` returns a `CompletionStage` which I can not figure out how to pipe it to an Akka actor.

So how can I properly use the play WS 2.5.x api from within an Akka actor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25):

> While Play 2.4 was cross compiled against both Scala 2.10 and Scala
>   2.11, this new release of Play is only available for Scala 2.11. The reason for dropping Scala 2.10 support is that Play has a new library
>   dependency on scala-java8-compat, which is only available for Scala
>   2.11. This library makes it easy to convert from and to common Scala and Java8 types, and hence it’s valuable to simplify the Play core.
>   Furthermore, you may also find it handy to use in your own Play
>   project. For example, if you need to convert Scala Future instances
>   into Java CompletionStage (or the other way around).

I am pretty sure [you can still do it easy](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat/blob/master/src/test/java/scala/compat/java8/FutureConvertersTest.java):

```
import static scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.*;

...

final Promise<String> p = promise();
final Future<String> sf = p.future();
final CompletionStage<String> cs = toJava(sf);
Future<String> sf1 = toScala(cs);
```